# What is the difference between a static object and static field?

Tags: java

I know that a static variable is shared by all the objects of the class.

But what about a static object? What is meant by a static object?

And what is the difference b/w static object and static field?

```
class B {
   int a;
   int b;
};

class A  {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     static B b=new B();  //what does this statement mean??
  }
}
```

Any explanation is highly appreciated.

if Static B b =new B(); is outside the method then it is compiling....

Comment: It is not a valid  statement...

Comment: if Static B b =new B(); is outside the method then it is compiling..

Comment: Correct.  But then it is just an ordinary static field.

Answer (score 2):

> But what about a static object? What is meant by static object?

Nothing. There is no such concept in Java.

> And what is the difference b/w static object and static field?

One of them doesn't exist in Java and the other does.

> static B b=new B();  //what does this statement mean??

Nothing. It doesn't compile in the context provided.